# Java Invalid maximum heap size

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, jvm, jvm-arguments

I just installed Ubuntu 64Bit on my VServer and JRE build 1.7.0_67-b01. 
If I want to run a java jar-file it says

> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

java -help says

> java version "1.7.0_67" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_67-b01) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

I tried 1M, 256M, 1024M, 2G and 4G for -Xmx, nothing works. Is there a hidden setting I don't know?

Here's the command I use:

```
java -Xmx 1024M -Xms 1024M -jar MyConverter.jar
```

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/invalid-initial-and-maximum-heap-size.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the space after Xmx and Xms

Comment: Thank you, I got this command from a tutorial. Now it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use more than 2G (say 4G with this switch: -Xmx4096m) make sure you have JRE for Windows x64 installed.

Answer (score -1):

I had a case related with incompatible line ending between Windows an Linux. So, if nothing helps, be sure your don't copied file from Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Check your RAM of machine. xmx shout be half of your  RAM. Also, xms is jvm heap size at starting whereas xmx is maximum heap size during jvm life cycle. It also depends on how much memory your application going to take during execution.